# Cannot connect to mouse via bluetooth automatically after reboot on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb, 18.04, mouse, bluetooth

I install Ubuntu 18.04 today(dual boot with Windows 10).And try to use bluetooth mouse(ELECOM M-XGM10BB) with USB bluetooth dongle(ELECOM LBT-UAN05C2/N).

At first, I connected to bluetooth mouse via GUI and succeed.

However, when I reboot, cannot connect to the mouse automatically(systemctl log says `Can't get HIDP connection info`).

note: the mouse is already trusted via bluetoothctl.

So, I start terminal and do below.

Using bluetoothctl, I succeeded to connect to the mouse manually.

Is there a way to connect to the mouse automatically?

```
$bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 00:1B:DC:0F:66:18 yumetodo-desktop [default]
[NEW] Device C8:47:82:27:DA:53 ELECOM BlueLED Mouse
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# devises
Invalid command
[bluetooth]# devices
Device C8:47:82:27:DA:53 ELECOM BlueLED Mouse
[bluetooth]# connect C8:47:82:27:DA:53
Attempting to connect to C8:47:82:27:DA:53
[CHG] Device C8:47:82:27:DA:53 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device C8:47:82:27:DA:53 Paired: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device C8:47:82:27:DA:53 ServicesResolved: yes
[ELECOM BlueLED Mouse]# exit
Agent unregistered
[DEL] Controller 00:1B:DC:0F:66:18 yumetodo-desktop [default]
$sudo systemctl status bluetooth
[sudo] yumetodo のパスワード: 
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-08-02 19:39:51 JST; 19min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 884 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─884 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

 8月 02 19:39:51 yumetodo-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
 8月 02 19:39:51 yumetodo-desktop bluetoothd[884]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
 8月 02 19:39:51 yumetodo-desktop systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
 8月 02 19:39:51 yumetodo-desktop bluetoothd[884]: Starting SDP server
 8月 02 19:39:51 yumetodo-desktop bluetoothd[884]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
 8月 02 19:56:49 yumetodo-desktop bluetoothd[884]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.88 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
 8月 02 19:56:49 yumetodo-desktop bluetoothd[884]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.88 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
 8月 02 19:57:45 yumetodo-desktop bluetoothd[884]: Can't get HIDP connection info
$/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --version
5.48
$lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04bb:0121 I-O Data Device, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0461:4d0e Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 057b:0020 Y-E Data, Inc. HEXA Media Drive 6-in-1 Card Reader Writer
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.028000] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.061483] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.491444] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin (v1.26)
[    3.122022] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.122032] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.122033] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.122035] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.122037] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.444418] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.444419] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.444421] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 1022.335434] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[ 1022.335446] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[ 1022.335455] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1078.024770] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[ 1078.024778] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[ 1079.357890] input: ELECOM BlueLED Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:71/0005:056E:00E5.0002/input/input25
[ 1079.362031] hid-generic 0005:056E:00E5.0002: input,hidraw1: BLUETOOTH HID v1.29 Mouse [ELECOM BlueLED Mouse] on 00:1b:dc:0f:66:18

$dpkg -l | grep bluez
ii  bluez                                      5.48-0ubuntu3.1                     amd64        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-cups                                 5.48-0ubuntu3.1                     amd64        Bluetooth printer driver for CUPS
ii  bluez-obexd                                5.48-0ubuntu3.1                     amd64        bluez obex daemon

$bluetoothctl --version
bluetoothctl: 5.48

$rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$cat -n /etc/bluetooth/main.conf | grep AutoEnable
    86  # AutoEnable defines option to enable all controllers when they are found.
    89  AutoEnable=true
```

journalctl log is below:

https://pastebin.com/vxz50bRd

```
 9月 16 13:31:28 yumetodo-desktop kernel: hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
 9月 16 13:31:28 yumetodo-desktop bluetoothd[1019]: Can't get HIDP connection info
 9月 16 13:31:28 yumetodo-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
 9月 16 13:31:28 yumetodo-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop kernel: hid-generic 0005:056E:00E5.0001: unknown main item tag 0x0
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop kernel: input: ELECOM BlueLED Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:69/0005:
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop kernel: hid-generic 0005:056E:00E5.0001: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v1.29 Mouse [ELECOM BlueLED Mouse] on 00:1b:dc:
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device ELECOM BlueLED Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1224]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device ELECOM BlueLED Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1224]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1224]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device ELECOM BlueLED Mouse (/dev/input/event22)
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (**) ELECOM BlueLED Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ELECOM BlueLED Mouse'
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1224]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device ELECOM BlueLED Mouse (/dev/input/event22)
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1224]: (**) ELECOM BlueLED Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1224]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ELECOM BlueLED Mouse'
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop upowerd[1185]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:6
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1224]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event22 13:86 fd 27 paused 1
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1224]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:86
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop upowerd[1185]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/h
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event22 13:86 fd 62 paused 0
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (**) ELECOM BlueLED Mouse: always reports core events
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event22"
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (II) event22 - ELECOM BlueLED Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (II) event22 - ELECOM BlueLED Mouse: device is a pointer
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (II) event22 - ELECOM BlueLED Mouse: device removed
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ELECOM BlueLED Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (**) ELECOM BlueLED Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (**) ELECOM BlueLED Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (**) ELECOM BlueLED Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (II) event22 - ELECOM BlueLED Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
 9月 16 13:31:29 yumetodo-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2137]: (II) event22 - ELECOM BlueLED Mouse: device is a pointer
```

---

On Windows 10, same issue was occurred and ElECOM support says below and work fine.

1. In Windows Device Manager, Bluetooth > Generic Bluetooth Radio. Open the Propaty, select Power Management tab, uncheck `Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power`
2. In Windows Controll Panel, Power Setting > current plan's `Change power plan settings` > `Change advanced power settings` > USB Setting > USB Selective suspend setting`, disable Selective suspend.
3. remove the mouse setting and reconnect

Ubuntu have something like the power management setting?

---

I'm already tried below posts:

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1387211
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390542
- [Linux PCにBluetooth機器を接続する - Qiita#OS起動時に自動的に接続するように設定する](https://qiita.com/shskwmt/items/fffabf521201f5835214#os%E8%B5%B7%E5%8B%95%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AB%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B): using udev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On ubuntu

1. `$sudo apt install chntpw`
2. Pair mouse via GUI
3. Restart PC

On Windows

4. Pair mouse via GUI
5. On administrator console, `powercfg.exe /hibernate off`
6. Restart PC

On Ubuntu

7. Mount Windows C Drive
8. Investigate Bluetooth interface ID

   ```
   $bluetoothctl
   Agent registered
   [CHG] Controller A4:C3:F0:88:90:45 Pairable: yes
   [ELECOM BlueLED Mouse]# exit
   ```

   In my case, that is `A4:C3:F0:88:90:45`.
9. Investigate mouse Bluetooth id using `chntpw`

   ```
   chntpw version 1.00 140201, (c) Petter N Hagen
   Hive </media/yumetodo/4C7E6CE87E6CCC70/Windows/System32/config/SYSTEM> name (from header): <SYSTEM>
   ROOT KEY at offset: 0x001020 * Subkey indexing type is: 686c <lh>
   File size 24379392 [1740000] bytes, containing 5276 pages (+ 1 headerpage)
   Used for data: 372635/23536872 blocks/bytes, unused: 87/38808 blocks/bytes.

   Simple registry editor. ? for help.

   >          

   > ls 
   Node has 17 subkeys and 0 values
   key name
   <ActivationBroker>
   <ControlSet001>
   <DriverDatabase>
   <HardwareConfig>
   <Input>
   <Keyboard Layout>
   <Maps>
   <MountedDevices>
   <ResourceManager>
   <ResourcePolicyStore>
   <RNG>
   <Select>
   <Setup>
   <Software>
   <State>
   <WaaS>
   <WPA>      

   > cd ControlSet001

   \ControlSet001> cd Service\BTHPORT

   \ControlSet001\Services\BTHPORT> cd Parameters\Keys

   (...)\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Keys> ls
   Node has 2 subkeys and 0 values
   key name
   <001bdc0f6618>
   <a4c3f0889045>

   (...)\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Keys> cd a4c3f0889045

   (...)\BTHPORT\Parameters\Keys\a4c3f0889045> ls
   Node has 0 subkeys and 1 values
   size     type              value name             [value if type DWORD]
       16  3 REG_BINARY         <c8478227da53>

   (...)\BTHPORT\Parameters\Keys\a4c3f0889045> hex c8478227da5.
   cat_vk: No such value <c8478227da5.>

   (...)\BTHPORT\Parameters\Keys\a4c3f0889045> hex c8478227da53
   Value <c8478227da53> of type REG_BINARY (3), data length 16 [0x10]
   :00000  08 57 94 6B D5 43 8B 13 30 0E 90 A8 1B 43 ED C7 .W.k.C..0....C..
   ```

   In almost every case, you should watch `ControlSet001`. However, `ControlSet002` is yet another possibility.
   `a4c3f0889045` is Bluetooth interface ID that was investigated at step 8.
   `08 57 94 6B D5 43 8B 13 30 0E 90 A8 1B 43 ED C7` is exactly what I want.
10. edit Bluetooth config

    ```
    $sudo nano "/var/lib/bluetooth/A4:C3:F0:88:90:45/C8:47:82:27:DA:53"/info
    ```

    ```
    [General]
    Name=ELECOM BlueLED Mouse
    Class=0x000580
    SupportedTechnologies=BR/EDR;
    Trusted=true
    Blocked=false
    Services=00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;

    [LinkKey]
    Key=0857946BD5438B13300E90A81B43EDC7
    Type=4
    PINLength=0

    [DeviceID]
    Source=2
    Vendor=1390
    Product=229
    Version=297
    ```

    Replace `Key` in `LinkKey` with the value investigated at step 9.
11. `$sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`
12. Now, the mouse was recognized at Ubuntu.
13. Restart PC

On Windows

14. Now, the mouse was recognized at Windows.
15. On administrator console, `powercfg.exe /hibernate on`

ref:

- https://orumin.blogspot.com/2019/02/bluetooth.html
- https://yumetodo.hateblo.jp/entry/2021/01/15/200421